# Volley and SlideTab layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-volley

I am using [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) to load some data. 
Now I have got a simple tab layout like [that](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout).

My question is actually:

Do I have to place the refresh layout inside of the tab layout or inside of each fragment?

Do I have to start loading the data inside of the ViewPager of the TabLayout or inside of each fragment?

And if I have to load the data inside of the ViewPager of the TabLayout - Do I have to past the data to each fragment ? 
Or should each fragment load the data by itself from the cache?

I was not able to find any post about using volley and TabLayout together

Comment: What is the nature of data in each fragment? Is data in each fragment independent of each other or related? Is the number of fragments fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data inside the each fragment of tabLayout is dynamic or you are loading that data using volley then you have to use  refresh layout for each fragment.
You have to cache the data by using `setOffscreenPageLimit();` call this method after you set the adapter

```
        pager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```